# Why Confusion Maxtrix and Model ACC are different

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, confusion-matrix

Currently, we are building the `Confusion Matrix` using `CNN`, which is different from `Model Acc`.

`Model ACC` is **92.3**% when **51%** accuracy is calculated using the `Confusion Matrix`.

Which of the following should be true for `Model ACC` and `Confusion Matrix` in this case?

And how do I fix the problem?

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics= 
['accuracy'])
hist = model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=10, epochs= 20, 
validation_data=test_generator, validation_steps=10 )
#5. Model Evaluate
print("-- Evaluate --")
scores = model.evaluate_generator(test_generator)
print("%s: %.2f%%" %(model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))

# 6.  Make Confusion Matrix
print("-- Predict --")
output = model.predict_generator(test_generator)
print('Counfusion Matrix')
output1 = np.argmax(output,axis=1)
cm1=confusion_matrix(test_generator.classes, output1)
print(cm1)
```

Comment: How's your result without augmentation(generator)? Actually same thing i have done except data-augmentation.

Comment: Hi i did try without data-augmentation but that time model has overfitting. Anyway you mean data-augmentation make problem right?

Comment: Which data-set you are using?

Comment: Now i using brain mri image

Comment: How the features in the this data-set? Actually performance are feature specific. Have you tried my solution on any other data-set?

Comment: Yes i tried MNI data set. Model acc is 100% but confusion matrix is 51%... Still problem...

Comment: Oh not mni actually mnist data set

Comment: Sorry, but i said, can you try it other data-sets like mnist, fashions etc. Otherwise you should edit your question or ask another one for mri data-set specific.

Comment: you must be doing sth wrong, i have given you example below.

Comment: Okay i will try another data set. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must doing something wrong, I ran a simple experiment on mnsit data-set, i got same result.

```
# my model loss and metric
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='adam',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
# fit model and train
# evaluate model
score = model.evaluate(X_train, Y_train1, verbose=1)
print('Val accuracy by model:', score[1])

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix as cm
pred = model.predict(X_train)
pred_label = [np.argmax(i) for i in pred]
actual_label = [np.argmax(i) for i in Y_train1]

cm1 = cm(pred_label, actual_label)
print('Val accuracy by confusion-metrics:', np.trace(cm1)/Y_train1.shape[0])
```

See the result:

```
Val accuracy by model: 0.9872380952380952
Val accuracy by confusion-metrics: 0.9872380952380952
```

Make sure, you are passing the right metrics and loss function.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer
I've added the code to the question, and I'd appreciate it if you could confirm it.